# Get-Help could not find MailChimpCmdlets in a help file in this session

Tags: powershell, api, email, mailchimp, saas

I'm looking for the documentation for `MailChimpCmdlets` through the console:

```
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> Install-Module -Name MailChimpCmdlets
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> Update-Help
```

yet there are no results returned:

```
(Get-InstalledModule -Name MailChimpCmdlets).InstalledLocation
```

shows:

```
/home/nicholas/.local/share/powershell/Modules/MailChimpCmdlets/20.0.7587.0
```

module:

- https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MailChimpCmdlets/20.0.7587.0
- https://www.cdata.com/drivers/mailchimp/powershell/
- https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/mailchimp-ado-powershell.rst

see also:

- [Where is the MailChimp Connector for PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65156395/4531180)

Comment: Did you install the module yet? `Install-Module -Name MailChimpCmdlets` And then `Get-Command -Module MailChimpCmdlets` to see what it provides. One of the pages you linked has usage examples it seems.

Comment: pardon, yes I installed it.

Comment: And where are you stuck? Did you read the usage examples? https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/mailchimp-ado-powershell.rst

Comment: I was only looking for documentation, pardon.  Even though I've "installed" the module, not sure it's actually there.  as above, commands come back as unrecognized.  but, I was only looking for help file.  thx.

Comment: what response do you get from >>> `(Get-InstalledModule -Name YourModuleNameGoesHere).InstalledLocation` <<<

Comment: there's a lengthy license in that directory, @Lee_Dailey so probably that's the problem.

Comment: @NicholasSaunders - that means the module _should_ be in that dir ... and that the dir is in your `$env:PSModulePath`. so things otta work if they are all there. you will likely need to deal with the mailchimp folks for why you are getting errors. [*sigh ...*] good luck!